# SDL2 создание диалогов окна

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl2

При изучении SDL2 встал вопрос как создать форму с полем ввода текста .

Что то вроде....

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в той документации, которой вы пользуетесь для изучения SDL2, не написано как это сделать?

Comment: К сожалению нечего внятного по этому вопросу не нашел на оф вики
https://wiki.libsdl.org/

Answer (score 3):

В SDL2 нет инструментов для поддержки "форм", если вы хотите такую получить, то вам нужно всё рисовать самостоятельно. Вероятно, есть какие-то библотеки для SDL которые [могут делать такое](http://members.chello.nl/w.boeke/SDL-widgets/index.html). Но не факт что на данном уровне освоения это будет полезно. В целом полезнее будет написать самостоятельно, [тут несколько советов](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/99098/communication-in-a-simple-gui-c-sdl2) по организации работы GUI если хочется от чего-то оттолкнуться.

Comment: Подозревал что всё придётся пилить ручками.
"Но не факт что на данном уровне освоения это будет полезно"  
Любая информация будет полезна в освоении новой технологии.

Comment: @hays я имел в виду что пользование библиотекой при обучении идёт скорее во вред чем на пользу (в некоторый противовес тому когда нужно быстро получить результат). По личному опыту в геймдев чем "ниже" берёте тем лучше. SDL - хороший вариант.

Comment: Нет просто мне в свое время было лень портировать с WinAPI всё что написал и принял решение что мне нужна кроссплатформенная мультимедийная библеотека а так при желании могу и с Motif познакомиться =)